# simple jQuery draggable implemention without jQuery-UI - how to turn off?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

I'm customizing a simplified "draggable" function available here: [Draggable without jQuery-UI](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/draggable-without-jquery-ui/), and this is what I have so far:

```
$.fn.extend({
        canDragMe: function(){
        return this.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this = $(this);
        return $this.css('cursor', opt.cursor).on("mousedown", function(e) {
            var $drag = $this.addClass('draggable');
                drg_h = $drag.outerHeight(),
                drg_w = $drag.outerWidth(),
                pos_y = $drag.offset().top + drg_h - e.pageY,
                pos_x = $drag.offset().left + drg_w - e.pageX;
            $drag.on("mousemove", function(e) {
                $('.draggable').offset({
                    top:e.pageY + pos_y - drg_h,
                    left:e.pageX + pos_x - drg_w
                }).on("mouseup", function() {
                    $this.removeClass('draggable');
                });
            });
            e.preventDefault(); // disable selection
        }).on("mouseup", function() {
                $this.removeClass('draggable');
            }
        });

    });
});
```

I'm going to use it like this: `$('#mydiv').canDragMe();`.
But I'm going to need to turn the drag on and off on an element according to user input.

So my question is, what's the simplest way to turn off the drag? Either like `$('#mydiv').canNotDragMe();` or maybe `$('#mydiv').canDragMe(false);` (which would need input options in the plugin of course).

### Edit

I understand I need some kind of implementation of unbinding the actions above from mousedown? Or some way to "destroy" the plugin?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why can't you use jQuery UI?

Comment: because of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14937777/console-trace-or-stack-trace-to-pinpiont-the-source-of-a-bug-in-javascript#comment20963146_14937777 - I can't figure out what's wrong, so I thought I might escape this bug by using a much simpler version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a basic `cannotDragMe` method by simply unbinding the handlers that are set in the original method. Since the original is using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), you can use [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) to turn them off in the new method.

**NOTE:** I also noticed that the code you provided was different than the code on the [site you referenced](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/draggable-without-jquery-ui/). The code on the site had better performance, so I used that instead. I also added [namespaces](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names) to the `.on()` and `.off()` events so that you don't accidentally unbind anything you are not intending to unbind.

**Updated jQuery Extend Method** - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8BXaj/2/)

```
$.fn.extend({
    cannotDragMe: function () {
        return this.each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this = $(this);
            return $this.css('cursor', 'default').off("mousedown.drag").off("mousemove.drag").off("mouseup.drag");
        });
    },
    canDragMe: function (opt) {
        opt = $.extend({
            handle: "",
            cursor: "move"
        }, opt);

        var $el;
        if (opt.handle === "") {
            $el = this;
        } else {
            $el = this.find(opt.handle);
        }

        return $el.css('cursor', opt.cursor).on("mousedown.drag", function (e) {
            var $drag;
            if (opt.handle === "") {
                $drag = $(this).addClass('draggable');
            } else {
                $drag = $(this).addClass('active-handle').parent().addClass('draggable');
            }
            var z_idx = $drag.css('z-index'),
                drg_h = $drag.outerHeight(),
                drg_w = $drag.outerWidth(),
                pos_y = $drag.offset().top + drg_h - e.pageY,
                pos_x = $drag.offset().left + drg_w - e.pageX;
            $drag.css('z-index', 1000).parents().on("mousemove.drag", function (e) {
                $('.draggable').offset({
                    top: e.pageY + pos_y - drg_h,
                    left: e.pageX + pos_x - drg_w
                }).on("mouseup.drag", function () {
                    $(this).removeClass('draggable').css('z-index', z_idx);
                });
            });
            e.preventDefault(); // disable selection
        }).on("mouseup.drag", function () {
            if (opt.handle === "") {
                $(this).removeClass('draggable');
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('active-handle').parent().removeClass('draggable');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: @user961627 I believe the main one is  putting the `draggable` class on the parent of the item that is being dragged. In the example you provided, if you moved your mouse around very fast, it would loose track of the item being dragged and it would stop moving. Since they are using the parent now, as long as you are within the parent's boundaries, this does not happen. Also, they put a z-index on the item that is being dragged. That is to ensure the item being dragged is always on top of other positioned elements on your page as you are moving it.